# .click() not functioning properly within a div

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website that lists down certain products. on the pages I have used a jQuery pagination to paginate the results. I used [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html) script for that purpose.

So all the product details are displayed within `class="data"` inside a `<li></li>`

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="loading"></div>
<div id="container">
       <div class="data"></div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Within those products I have link that allows the products to added to the list.

```
<span class="addlist">
<a id="id_1249" class="m-btn" onclick="return false" href="http://index.php/action/add/">Add</a>
</span>
```

I have created a simple function to check the click event

```
$(".addlist").click(function() {
   alert("clicked."); 
 });
```

The problem is when i click on the add link nothing happens and doesn't prompt the message.

After testing for a long time i noticed, when i place a link (`<a href="index.php" class="addlist">Visible Text</a>`) outside the `<div id="container">` the click event works perfect. but if its placed inside the `<div id="container">` it doesn't work. i added the `$.noConflict();` within the jQuery function, but still no use.

Can someone please tell me what might the problem be?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ynk3f/ works for me

Comment: @Andrey: I think this is more to do with the way the fiddle is wrapping script in a `document.ready(function(){...})` or `window.onload=function(){};` as required. The `return false` looks suspicious , specially as it is within an inline `onclick` which always executed first before any script not being inline. We would need to know if the OPs code is wrapped in a `document.ready..` or not possibly also get a full HTML view in which the `a` link is in.

Comment: @Andrey it doesn't work when the content loads for the pagination.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl if i remove the false it goes to the next page. i want to do some ajax post and prompt a message than moving to the link.

Comment: @LiveEn: I'm sure the `return false` works for you in that sense but it executes before anything else as it is inline, preventing the event from bubbling up to the bound event. In-line script is a pain to debug with. Assuming it is valid HTML, how about wrapping the `a` tag around the `span` instead? : `<a id="id_1249" class="m-btn" onclick="return false" href="http://index.php/action/add/"><span class="addlist">Add</span></a>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since your `addlist` is added dynamically you need to use `on()` delegated event..

```
$("#container").on('click',".addlist",(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked."); 
 });
```

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about on() delegated event

Answer (score 2):

I think you're returning false too quickly.

Try doing:

HTML

```
<span class="addlist">
<a id="id_1249" class="m-btn" href="http://index.php/action/add/">Add</a>
</span>
```

JS

```
$(".addlist").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("clicked."); 
 });
```

Comment: His code works http://jsfiddle.net/Ynk3f/ , there is something that he didn't mention.

Comment: @Andrey the problem was because the content is dynamic. The solution is what bipen mentioned. `on()` delegated event.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.addlist', function() {
   alert("clicked."); 
});
```

The elements may not exist on document ready.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you have `return false` as an on click handler on the anchor. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: without the false it moves to the next page once i click. what i want to do is do some ajax post and prompt the message than moving to the link.